# Entropy calculation on a time serie moving window

Tags: matlab, entropy

I have just started playing with Matlab and I would like to get the entropy value for a moving window.

I have a time serie ts 1432x1 and I would like to get the entropy value for a moving window length= N, so if N = 40 I should get first entropy value for the ts(1:40), then ts(2:41) and so on up to the latest ts point.

The output should be an array 1392x1 (N points shorter than the input time serie).

I am interested in any different entropy method.

**Edit** I have tried this example found in Matlab central, but it doesn't work

```
function [vectorout]=entropy_moving(vectorin,eFave)

    l_vectorin=length(vectorin);
    l_half_interval=eFave;

    ifor1=1;
    for ifor1=1:l_vectorin

        if ifor1>l_half_interval&&ifor1<(l_vectorin-l_half_interval)
            vectorout(ifor1)=shannon_entro(vectorin(ifor1-l_half_interval:ifor1+l_half_interval));

        elseif ifor1>=(l_vectorin-l_half_interval)
            vectorout(ifor1)=shannon_entro(vectorin(ifor1:l_vectorin));

        end
    end
```

where I have used shannon_entro instead of wentropy. Any help really appreciated.

PS posted here also since got no answer in Matlab central.

**Update:**  To better explain what I should get, I have created 5 different 40 point length series, and calculate for each one the wentropy.

Result is shown here

[image]

The for loop should return an array 861x1 whose first 5 values must be out1_40, out2_41, out3_42 and so on.

I have uploded here

[Full serie](http://pastebin.com/uPUYbCMY)

[1_40](http://pastebin.com/KxTiM0yW)

[2_41](http://pastebin.com/04wwi6At)

[3_42](http://pastebin.com/dggRU3b3)

[4_43](http://pastebin.com/YaeWRV7u)

[5_44](http://pastebin.com/z1SmfDqk)

All txt files I have used. Thanks

Comment: How do you calculate entropy?

Comment: There are different ways to calculate entropy: one is the function e = wentropy(ts, 'shannon') that returns a value for the ts passed as parameter, otherwise there are different methods available in Matlab central exchange

Comment: @Albertoacepsut have you tried a simple `for` loop?

Comment: @Dan Yes following an example in Central exchange, I have tried this:

function [vectorout]=entropy_moving(vectorin,eFave)

l_vectorin=length(vectorin);
l_half_interval=eFave;
ifor1=1;
for ifor1=1:l_vectorin
if ifor1>l_half_interval&&ifor1<(l_vectorin-l_half_interval)
vectorout(ifor1)=shannon_entro(vectorin(ifor1-l_half_interval:ifor1+l_half_interval));

    elseif ifor1>=(l_vectorin-l_half_interval)
        vectorout(ifor1)=shannon_entro(vectorin(ifor1:l_vectorin));   
    end
end But it doesn't work; any help really appreciated

Comment: @Albertoacepsut please rather add that code to your question...

Comment: @Dan question updated

Comment: @Albertoacepsut can you be specific regarding what doesn't work about that code?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with the code you posted aside from it be rather cumbersome. Here is the same idea using `wentropy`:

```
vectorout = zeros(numel(vectorin),1)
for e = 1:numel(vectorin)
    vectorout(e) = wentropy(vectorin(e:min(e+eFave-1, end)), 'shannon');
end
```

So long as you use of `wentropy` or `shannon_entro` is correct, this aught to work (and is really the same as the code you posted). If your code doesn't work, I would suspect the problem lies within your `shannon-entro` function